# Oracle VirtualBox networking - Can I make a network that doesn't use any of the host computers?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtualization, virus, anti-virus

I'm planning to test viruses, and I don't want it getting to my other computers on my network, so nobody else will be mad. Is there a way to make a network like that?

I've been watching danooct1 and rogueamp.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can set the networking mode to [Internal networking](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_internal). Create a new internal network, set each VM to use that network, and either [enable the Virtualbox DHCP server](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-dhcpserver) or set up the IP addresses manually.

[image: Network settings page]

Once you do this, the VMs will be attached to their own internal network, provided by a virtual switch managed by the VirtualBox driver. The guests will be able to see each other, but the host machine and any network it's attached to will be inaccessible to the guests.